# ::before pseudo element not working in makeStyles

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, makestyles

I am using `makeStyles` in react and I cannot figure out why the `::before` content won't show. It will work if I make the content a picture but it doesn't show with text.

To clarify further the `::before` element is not being rendered at all.

```js
cardPoint: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    justifySelf: 'start',
    maxWidth: '250px',
    position: 'relative',
    "&::before": {
        content: 'Look at me',
        display: 'inline-block',
        color: '#000',
    },
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to pass `'Look at me'` as `'"Look at me"'`:

Comment: Thanks a lot @Luis Sardon